# Whats wrong with this code? [MySQL request cell info]

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row("$result");
$id = $row[2];
```

Comment: Take a look at your fetch row statement. 
And, does your query have two columns?

Comment: @stUrb you mean (atleast) 3 columns?

Comment: That's what i meant yeah :) It's 2 am here in Holland (long day) :)

Comment: It's 6 AM here in India. Small night? :P #totally irrelevant, sleepless people talking

Answer (score 4):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

when you use a variable inside a double quoted string it will be casted to a string. and you cannot pass mysql_fetch_result a string, but only a mysql result

Answer (score 2):

The following statement:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row("$result");
```

must be like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: hah i've been four seconds faster xD

Comment: @zolex: Whoever explains ***why*** first can have my upvote. :)

Comment: @zolex meh! I typed a whole sentence there. :|

Comment: @animuson when you use a variable inside a double quoted string it will be casted to a string. and you cannot pass mysql_fetch_result a string, but only a mysql result.

Answer (score 2):

please correct this line 
    $row = mysql_fetch_row("$result");
to
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

U dont need the "s for the variable in 2nd line...try debugging using var_dump in each step and see where the error is coming in these kinds of situations. U can also see if the query had any problems by doing this
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ") or die("Error with query");

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```